# How to show region name and Gdp value on placing cursor on any region of a world map which is shown in the popup?

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

Im using JvectorMap for creating world map.

My code is like this:

```
var gdpData = {
  "AF": 16.63,
  "AL": 11.58,
  "DZ": 158.97,
  ...
};
$('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap({
  map: 'world_mill_en',
  series: {
    regions: [{
      values: gdpData,
      scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
      normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
    }]
  },
  onRegionLabelShow: function(e, el, code){
    el.html(el.html()+' (GDP - '+gdpData[code]+')');
  }
});
```

it is showing map like this:
[image]

In the above map if im placing cursor on Russia REGION it is   showing a tool tip country name and its Gdp count value like Russia(GDP-1476.91)

I have added a button somewhere else and  On clicking of the btton im showing popup in that popup im displaying the same worldmap.
But in that popup if im placing  cursor on  any region it is not showing Country name with GDP value..

can anyone help me pls..

Comment: check your region name z-index, it might be less than your popup z-index, which is causing the region name to be hidden.

Comment: What You  said is absolutely working.. You saved my day.. Thanks a lot Ramesh..

Comment: good Santhosh, i wrote it as an answer please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your region name `z-index`, it might be less than your popup `z-index`, which is causing the region name to be hidden.